# Is there any shorthand if statement in python? (Be specific I didn't mean shorthand if-else statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any shorthand for if statements?

```
print('Bla-Bla-Bla') if true    # like this
print('Bla-Bla-Bla') if true else print('Bla-Bla')    # not this
```

Comment: `if true: print('Bla-Bla-Bla')` ? (although I would rather keep proper indentation)

Comment: you can also `print('Bla-Bla-Bla') if true else 1` which will do the same, but is probably bad practice

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional:

```
print('Bla-Bla-Bla' if True else 'Bla-Bla')
print('Bla-Bla-Bla' if False else 'Bla-Bla')
```

Basically, if the statement for the `if` is `True` then it will print whatever is in front of it. If not, it will print whatever is after `else`. If you don't need the `else` statement, you can do a one-liner (though try avoiding them):

```
if True: print "true"
```

This is often to save bytes since more characters (like spaces) means more bytes.

Comment: What's wrong with this? I posted this practically the same time as the other answer so seeing this as a duplicate or vice versa is extremely hard if not impossible

Comment: This shouldn't be down voted as it is valid and was answered when Simon did.

Comment: I've also updated my answer due to comment from Chris_Rands; therefore, they are also two different answers as well now.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer:

What you want is spelled:

```
if condition:
    do_something()
```

IOW, no, what you're asking for doesn't exist.

## Long answer

You *could* write it either as

```
print("foo") if condition else 1 # or whatever
```

or

```
if condition: print("foo")
```

but both are considered bad style (and even quite WTF'y for the first one) and any pythonista working on your code will immediatly replace it with the proper idiom (cf "short answer") so it doesn't hurt his/her eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional to generate the argument to the print function:

```
print('Bla-Bla-Bla' if True else 'Bla-Bla')
print('Bla-Bla-Bla' if False else 'Bla-Bla')
```

prints:

```
Bla-Bla-Bla
Bla-Bla
```

Comment: This is no point in using `.format` here; there is no formatting!

Answer (score 0):

```py
bar > foo and x or y
```

where `bar > foo` is an expression/condition 
`and` works when the condition is True (positive value) 
`or` when False (negative value).